# Can a range of negative and positive numbers be used to pattern match using Like in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pattern-matching

I have a user entered string:

```
"{0.3064, 15.6497, 60.7668, 52.1362, 76.6645, 97, -15.8315, -6.8806, 5.547, -2.3381, -23.9905, 40.4569, 60.1592, 27.1418, 42.9375, -22.8297, -11.7423, -17.1576, -33.9918, 7.0585}"
```

and I would like to be able to validate it based on having a "{" at the start, a "}" at the end and twenty comma separated numbers between -1000 and 1000 in between the commas.

I have tried using the like operator as below with no luck.  Everything returns False no matter whether it matches the patter or not.  How can I validate based on this pattern.

This is what I have tried:

```
ArrayOk = ArrayValues1txt.Text Like "{[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000],[(1000)-1000]}"
If ArrayOk = False Then
MsgBox("Wrong array pattern!  Pattern must contain 20 elements and be in the form {#,#}",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, "Bad Array Entered")
    GoTo Canceller
    Else
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx to validate the general pattern of: Are there 20 decimal values separated by commas wrapped in curly brackets?

```vb
Dim pattern = "^{((-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s?){19}(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)}$"
Dim input = "{0.3064, 15.6497, 60.7668, 52.1362, 76.6645, 97, -15.8315, -6.8806, 5.547, -2.3381, -23.9905, 40.4569, 60.1592, 27.1418, 42.9375, -22.8297, -11.7423, -17.1576, -33.9918, 7.0585}"

If (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)) Then

End If
```

Once you validated that it matches the specific pattern, you can validate that the numbers match the numeric range validation by doing the following:

1. Remove the brackets from the String
2. Split the string by a comma
3. Trim any excessive whitespace from the items
4. Convert the items to fractional values (Double, Decimal, etc.)
5. Check if the items are within range

You can do a lot of those steps using LINQ which would make it much more concise:

```vb
Dim pattern = "^{((-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s?){19}(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)}$"
Dim input = "{0.3064, 15.6497, 60.7668, 52.1362, 76.6645, 97, -15.8315, -6.8806, 5.547, -2.3381, -23.9905, 40.4569, 60.1592, 27.1418, 42.9375, -22.8297, -11.7423, -17.1576, -33.9918, 7.0585}"

If (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)) Then
    input = input.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty)
    Dim items = input.Split(",")
    Dim convertedItems = items.Select(Function(item) Convert.ToDouble(item.Trim())).ToArray()
    If (convertedItems.All(Function(item) item >= -1000 AndAlso item <= 1000)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("All of the items are within -1000 and 1000")
    End If
End If
```

Here is a live demo: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gmoloH)

Answer (score 0):

I used `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWith` to test for the  braces. Next I chopped them off with `Substring`. I then split the string by commas. I checked whether there were exactly 20 elements.

If we get this far, I loop through each element. Trim off any leading or trailing spaces and change it to a double. Then I can do the number comparison.

```
Private Function ValidateArray(input As String) As Boolean
    If Not input.StartsWith("{") OrElse Not input.EndsWith("}") Then
        Return False
    End If
    input = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2)
    Dim splits = input.Split(","c)
    If splits.Length <> 20 Then
        Return False
    End If
    For Each n In splits
        Dim dbl = CDbl(n.Trim)
        If dbl > 1000 OrElse dbl < -1000 Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim IsValid = ValidateArray("{0.3064, 15.6497, 60.7668, 52.1362, 76.6645, 97, -15.8315, -6.8806, 5.547, -2.3381, -23.9905, 40.4569, 60.1592, 27.1418, 42.9375, -22.8297, -11.7423, -17.1576, -33.9918, 7.0585}")
    MessageBox.Show(IsValid.ToString)
End Sub
```